# Bigcommerce Webhooks work for Apps?

Tags: bigcommerce

When I hit https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/HASH/v2/hooks I get 
403
{"error":"You are authorized but your scope does not include this resource."}

Using
X-Auth-Token
X-Auth-Client
Credentials work for other endpoints, i.e. https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/HASH/v2/products

And if I use the wrong credentials I get a different response (401)

I reauthorized via oAuth but no change. The docs said web hooks should be in the default scope.

Comment: hi i am having the same issue can  you tell me what worked for you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue. It's a bad error message- the problem has nothing to do with authentication, access scopes, etc. In all likelihood you simply need to specify your response type as JSON in your request headers:

`Accept: application/json`

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you're doing a GET, and not a POST.

A POST to the same URL (i.e POST /stores/{store_hash}/v2/hooks ) creates a WebHook, in which case you would need to set a scope in your request headers. A GET will return a list of registered hooks and no scope is required

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before. You need to change the 'HASH' part with your actual store hash. This can be found in the URL in the admin...